# Magento2.4: How to add export option from sales order grid to in ACL list?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3, magento2.2, magento2.4

I want to add export option from sales order grid to ACL list, so i can put restriction on this option and only allowed user roles can access this option or not visible to them who does not have access to this option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> app/code/Dotsquares/SalesOrder/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <listingToolbar name="listing_top">    
        <exportButton name="export_button" class="Dotsquares\SalesOrder\Ui\Component\ExportButton" />
    </listingToolbar>
</listing>
```

> app/code/Dotsquares/SalesOrder/Ui/Component/ExportButton.php

```
<?php
namespace Dotsquares\SalesOrder\Ui\Component;

use Magento\Framework\AuthorizationInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;

class ExportButton extends \Magento\Ui\Component\ExportButton
{
    private $authorization;

    public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context,
        UrlInterface $urlBuilder,
        AuthorizationInterface $authorization,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $urlBuilder, $components, $data);
        $this->authorization = $authorization;
    }

    /**
     * @return void
     */
    public function prepare()
    {
        parent::prepare();
        $context = $this->getContext();
        $config = $this->getData('config');
        if (isset($config['options']))
        {
            $options = [];
            foreach ($config['options'] as $option)
            {
                $additionalParams = $this->getAdditionalParams($config, $context);
                $option['url'] = $this->urlBuilder->getUrl($option['url'], $additionalParams);
                $options[] = $option;
            }
            $config['options'] = $options;

            if (!$this->authorization->isAllowed('Magento_Sales::export'))
            {
                $config = [];
            }

            $this->setData('config', $config);
        }
    }
}
```

> app/code/Dotsquares/SalesOrder/etc/acl.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <resource id="Magento_Backend::admin">
                <resource id="Magento_Sales::sales" title="Sales" translate="title" sortOrder="20">
                    <resource id="Magento_Sales::export"  title="Export Permission" translate="title" sortOrder="40" />
                </resource>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

Comment: You can select and un-select checkbox permission from user Roles. Please see the screenshot. https://tinyurl.com/2a8826fd

Answer (score 0):

> You mean this option wants to add to the ACL list? or do you want to add an export option in mass action ?

[image]

Comment: you are right, i want to add this option in ACL list.

Comment: Ok, I am going to add another answer for this solution. That will work like a charm!!

Comment: I have added please see.